# Using Spring or Lambda for bulk event trigger

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-dataflow

Looking for some help on an application design. I am using spring framework and hosting application in AWS.

I am working on an enterprise Java Web application that is suppose to handle events when their trigger time is reached. For example, consumers can set an event to begin on 12/20/22 at 07:35 AM, and system is suppose to send a notification when that time is reached.

I can store these events in a database along with their trigger time and setup a Spring scheduler (@Scheduler) to run every minute and process events whose trigger time is reached. My only concern with this approach is, there could be hundreds/thousands of event to trigger at any minute, and it cannot be processed within one minute.

Is there any alternate way to design this? I don't know if Spring offers a feature where I could create these Event, and Frameworks trigger these events when trigger time is reached. In that way, I can stay away from managing Scheduling and Triggering part.

I am using AWS to host this applications, so another option I'm thinking towards is creating an AWS lambda for every such Event, and let AWS manage the triggering part. In that way, I can stay away from managing the triggers.

Let me know your views? Or If you came across similar problems and how you resolved that?

Comment: "I don't know if Spring offers a feature where I could create these Event, and Frameworks trigger these events when trigger time is reached." Yes the Spring scheduler lets you schedule events programmatically in your code. You don't have to rely on the `@Scheduler` annotation.

Comment: What takes place when each schedule runs?  Do you have to go through the Spring code or is it a relatively simple notification?

Comment: @stdunbar There is some processing involved before each notification is emailed to the consumers.

Comment: @MarkB.. The challenge is whether Spring Scheduler is right approach here? I can use even a Cron to trigger this process every minute, but number of events to process is large and I am thinking that program may not process all the events in one minute.

Comment: @Kul I didn't post an answer, just a comment clarifying one point in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using spring-cloud-dataflow to manage this as tasks and streams.

You create a custom batch application that will use @Scheduled to check the your database when events are dure and then send events to a stream. You can use Spring Integration APIs to interact with RabbitMQ or Kafka topics.

The event should contain enough information needed to process the event.
You then have a stream application that produces the content and send via email or pass it on to a separate stream app that sends the email.
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/programming-models/

The flow will look something like:
:mail_events | message-processor | message-sender

You will configure property for mail_events to match the topic created and configured for you mail-event-batch application.

You can use Spring Cloud Data Flow to manage the mail-event-batch application as well.
You can scale each application https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/scaling/